# Underground Propane line to fire pit

Tags: propane, fire-pit

I'm building a propane fire pit in my backyard patio with a pea stone surface.  I want to have the LP tank located 12 feet away from the fire, and I don't want to trip over the line.  What can I do for an underground connection for a small application like this?  For the burner, I'll be buying a kit from FirePitsDirect.com.

Comment: If the fire pit is close enough to the house, you might want to consider tapping into the natural gas line of the house. It'll be a bit more work, but you won't have to refill your propane tank.

Answer (score 1):

I did more research on this topic and decided to go with CSST (corrugated stainless steel tubing) inside a PVC conduit.  All material is available at Home Depot.
Good references are propane101.com and homeflex.com
BTW, I don't have a natural gas line in my home.

Answer (score 0):

Copper, steel and polyethylene are typically used for propane & natural gas - check your local code.  I'd probably go with black iron pipe - it's cheap, tough, readily available, and relatively easy to work with.  Dope the connections with pipe dope approved for gas, and pressure test the assembly before putting it into service.  It should be buried at least 12" deep.

Note that the CSST (Corrugated Stainless Steel Tube) flexible gas line typically requires a conduit for direct burial.

Answer (score -4):

**WARNING: This answer recommends action that might be dangerous or illegal**

PVC pipe works fine for low pressure gas. Put the regulator at the tank and run PVC to ,the pit.

Comment: PVC pipe is not approved for propane (NFPA 58, section 5.9.3)